# Running loops inside PHPExcel and Formatting

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am trying to create an excel with PHPExcel, and need to have a certain way of formatting.

Like so,

header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6

row1    row1

row2    row2                    row2    row2

row1    row1

row2    row2                    row2    row2

row2    row2                    row2    row2

The sql query for the loops would be like this

```
loop1 {
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$sql1array = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)
$row1 = $sql1array['column1'];

loop2 {
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE column1 = $row1");
$sql2array = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)
$row2 = $sql2array['column1'];

}
}
```

I can pull the data fine, but I need more help with the formatting.

Thanks for any advice or help with this.

Comment: How do you need help? What specific issue do you have?

Comment: Yeah sorry the table didn't show like I had thought it would.  I am trying to format with PHExcel.  I am trying to place loop 1 data on row 1 from header 1-4, and then loop2 is based of table1 and table2 ids matching.  Then place the data from table 2 on row 2 starting at headers 1-2 and 5-6. I hope that this makes sense.